How can binding from internal View model to method in ASP.NET
This is my view model that have internal view model:
public class CartViewModel
{
     public List<CartItemViewModel> Items { get; set; } = new List<CartItemViewModel>();
     public List<CartAddressViewModel> CartAddresses { get; set; }
     public CartDeliveryAndPaymentDetails CartDeliveryDateViewModel { get; set; }
     public decimal Tax { get; set; }

     public decimal TotalPrice
     {
         get
         {
             return Items.Sum(item => item.ChefFoodsPrice * item.Quantity);
         }
     }

     public decimal FinalPrice
     {
         get
         {
             return TotalPrice + (TotalPrice * Tax / 100);
         }
     }

     public enum CartViewModelResult
     {
         CartCreatedSuccess,
         CartCreatedFail,
         CartNotFound
     }
}

And this is my internal view model:
public class CartDeliveryAndPaymentDetails
{
    public DateTime DeliveryDate { get; set; }
    public string DeliveryTime { get; set; }
 
    public string Details { get; set; }
     
    public PaymentType PaymentMethod { get; set; }
}

But in my method, I can not get property in model in entrance value and return null: it is internal view model but I can not get value from asp-for:
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SaveDeliveryAndPaymentDetails(CartDeliveryAndPaymentDetails details)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _orderService.SaveDeliveryAndPaymentDetailsInSession(details);
        return RedirectToAction("ShowCart");
    }

    // If ModelState is not valid, return to the same view to show validation errors
    return  RedirectToAction("ShowCart") ;
}

And this is part of my view, my main view model is a CartViewModel and I always get null returned:
<section>
    <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="SaveDeliveryAndPaymentDetails" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label class="text-muted ml-2"> Delivery Date</label>
   
                 <label><i class="fa fa-fw fa-calendar"></i></label>
                    <input asp-for="CartDeliveryDateViewModel.DeliveryDate" type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="2017-06-04" id="mdate">
                    <span asp-validation-for="CartDeliveryDateViewModel.DeliveryDate" class="text-danger"></span>
                    //      ....
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</section>


Does only CartDeliveryDateViewModel.DeliveryDate get null or every property is null? Did you submit all the field?

@QiangFu  every property were null
